Using Ngx-Editor with Angular 17 Server-side Rendering
I have an Angular project (v.17.3.0) and I am trying to use ngx-editor (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-editor) (v.17.5.4). The problem I'm running into is that importing the library throws an error:
12:34:46 PM [vite] Internal server error: Unexpected token ':' at new AsyncFunction (<anonymous>) at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/.../projects/ngxEditorTest/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:54894:28)
To replicate, create a new Angular app with server-side rendering, install ngx-editor with npm install ngx-editor, clear out the app.component.html template, and set the app.component.ts code to this:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EditorComponent } from './editor/editor.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [EditorComponent],
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {}

When I do the same with SSR disabled it works as expected. My first thought was to put it in a component and only render the component on the client, but even then I'd have to import the component which imports the ngx-editor, which again throws the same error. Any advice?
